# Find the limit of this as n tends to infinity

Tags: analysis, limits

Find the limit of this as n tends to infinity:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+3}}+....+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$

What I tried:
If n tends to infinity, all the fractions will tend to 0? But i dont think thats the right answer. I struggle with how to use the squeeze rule for summation-limit questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** try to [squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) like
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}}=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}\leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+....+\color{green}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}\leq \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$
and see that the limit is $1$.

Simply because $$\color{green}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i+1}}\leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}, \forall i=0..n$$
and if we sum all the terms we get
$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\color{green}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}\leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i+1}}\leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68960/discussion-on-answer-by-rtybase-find-the-limit-of-this-as-n-tends-to-infinity).